# Docusign Completed Documents not coming on Mailinator Account

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Docusign PHP SDK and currently using mailinator mail accounts for beta users. I am not able to receive Email from Docusign post signature. Is there any issue with my account or it's something to do with Mailinator.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for mailinator being the culprit. Try with a fresh account from someone like the google people.